# Python: Variable to access object orientation?

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to use object orientation to create a game. I want to be able to access rooms and run activities but only be able to run certain activities in each room. I have all the activities assigned to a Object and I want to use the variable that the player typed in to access the Objects' variables then print what they did in the room.

```
    if activitiesList[i] == choice2:
        convert = (activitiesList2[i + 1])
        convert = str(convert)
        print ('You', a.convert, 'in', a.name)
```

Convert gets the name of the activity from the list then I want it to tell the Object which variable it's looking for.
Everything I have tried just results in the program looking for the attribute 'convert' in the Object. 
How do i get it to search for the attribute that the player chose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but I suspect you want `getattr`:

```
action = getattr(a, convert)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access an attribute dynamically, you can use the [**`getattr()`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
try:
    value = getattr(a, attribute_name)
except AttributeError:
    # attribute not found
    pass
```

Alternatively, you can also provide a default value to be returned if the attribute does not exist, instead of an exception to be thrown:

```
value = getattr(a, attribute_name, default_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a dict instead of a list?

```
stuff_in_room = {'hammer': ...}
if action in stuff_in_room:
    # do something
else:
    # can't do that
```

Comment: I did think of this but that would be a huge amount of if statements and code and I wanted a way to do this more quickly

Comment: Ok, then I must have misunderstood your question. Good luck with the game!